# App to plot my hike on google map?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications

I'm looking for an app that will periodically plot my coordinates on a map which I can directly or through an export/import, put onto a google map. Is there something that does this?

Comment: Most of the apps I'm familiar with store your track online, and you can usually download it from their site.  Would that be suitable?

Comment: @AdamDavis I'm ok with having to go through a browser - as long as the map isn't stored in some proprietary way, or accessible only through their site. I need to be able to access it through google maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Kinetic](http://kineticgps.com/)

For all my tracking needs I've become a fan of Kinetic. Accuracy is good. The customizable screens mean you can tailor the view for the activity. For example: I have a simple screen for when I ride my bike that's easy to access when I'm moving fast, versus a more complicated screen I'll use on hikes.

The routes are [exportable via email](http://kinetic.tenderapp.com/kb/questions/how-do-i-export-my-data) in formats that Google Earth and Maps will happily read (like [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)).

Comment: Well they have one new customer.  I'm impressed with all this app does, and how well it does it.  Or claims, to anyway, I'll have to take it out for a spin and see if it lives up to its claims.

Comment: @AdamDavis you're not the AD user I've turned on to Kinetic.

Answer (score 2):

## [Trails](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trails-gps-tracker/id289190494?mt=8)

I've used this app to track my MTB trails. You can [export](http://trails.lamouroux.de/exporting-tracks.html) the `.gpx` files and see them in google earth right on your iOS device.

> - Record waypoints with altitude for multiple tracks.
> - Edit recorded tracks on the map: name waypoints or delete unwanted ones.
> - See the distance, speed and duration of your track while you record.
> - No internet connection required during tracking.
> - Display your tracks OpenStreetMaps and select between road and topographic maps (that include cycle roads)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/iphone/12-must-have-iphone-apps-for-when-you-go-hiking-this-fall.xhtml) had a recommendation for the hiking apps - [AccuTerra](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/accuterra-on-demand-maps-gps/id324036903?mt=8). The app seems to provide the functionality that you're looking for. The review notes that:

> The app tracks your trail as you hike, allowing you to place markers
>   at significant points along the way and review your hike duration,
>   distance, pace, and elevation gain at any point. **All maps are stored
>   in your phone’s memory, so no reception is no problem.**

From the iTunes app page, the app claims to:

> - Unlimited Tracks! There is no limit to the number of hikes/tracks that can be recorded.
> - Unlimited Waypoints! There is no limit to the number of geo-located points that can be recorded.
> - Unlimited Geo-coded pictures! Photos taken within AccuTerra On Demand are linked to your adventures and can be displayed in the
>     location in which they were taken.
> - Real-time elevation profile and travel statistics.
> - Easily toggle and track between AccuTerra Maps and basic online maps
> - **Share your adventure. Upload directly from AccuTerra into your Facebook™ account, or send your tracks and photos via an email link
>     for viewing in Google Maps™ or Google Earth™**

Comment: There's a review on the app about it not having any (or many) apps for areas outside of California. Any idea about this?

Comment: I've been able to get by with this version, since I mainly hike in California. You may want to check out the Unlimited version of their app if you need more maps in the US (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/accuterra-unlimited-maps-gps/id355787609?mt=8). It claims to have "over five million square miles of terrain and trail maps in the contiguous US and Hawaii"